# ExstJs Store callback proper error handling

Tags: extjs

I want to receive a personalized error message when trying to load a store and my connection times out or the DB it's not accessible ... when I do an Ajax Request is very easy because I get "response" as a parameter either in success or failure ...

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',
   success: function(response, opts) {
      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      console.dir(obj);
   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
   }
});
```

But I'm facing problems to do the same when trying to load a store, I've defined a callback function but I only receive records, operation and success.

```
store.load({
        callback : function(records, options, success) {
            if (!success) {

              // what can I do here to show personalized error sent from server
            }
        }
    });
```

**So, what is the proper way to handle a response like this to show it to the user?**

```
{"success": false, "msg": "SomeExceptionFromServer"}
```

Best regards

Comment: Hummm already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694012/how-to-get-responsecode-from-store-callback though any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why not process your json response based on your `success` flag?

Comment: I do that but I want to display the exception sent from the server, where do I get that?

Comment: Where do you get the json string from in your `callback`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When success is false operation never gets a response property instead it gets a getError method, but you should define a messageProperty in the proxyReader in order to work.

Example:

```
Ext.define("SC.store.SegurosCancelacionStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    model: "SC.model.PersonaSeguro",
    proxy: {
        timeout: 90000,
        actionMethods: {
            read   : 'POST'
        },
        type: "ajax",
        url: "../SegurosFinsolCancelacionServlet",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root: "seguros",
            messageProperty : 'msjError' //without this, it doesn't work
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false
});
```

Implementation:

```
storeSegurosCancelacion.load({
                params: {
                    'sucursal':sucursal,
                    'persona': persona
                },
                callback:function(records, operation, success){
                    msg.hide();
                    if(success == true){
                        if(records.length == 0){
                         Ext.Msg.alert('Resultado', 'No se ha encontrado informaci&oacute;n');
                        }
                    }
                    if(success == false){
                        try{
                             Ext.Msg.alert('Error', operation.getError()); // way more elegant than ussing rawData etc ...
                        }catch(e){
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Error  inesperado en el servidor.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Best regards

Comment: there is an awesome thread in Sencha about this, but I couldn't find it just now, but I'll keep looking for it to refer it.

Comment: here is it http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196013-access-operation.response-when-success-false

Answer (score 0):

```
store.load({
        callback : function(records, operation, success) {

              console.log(operation.getResponse().msg);//this does the trick            

        }
    });
```

Comment: hi, i was trying to get this when success if false, however for some reason my error is saying undefined. i am using extjs 4.2, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If there is an error that you want to send, why not pass an empty `data` property along with the error message? So there are no records to load, but you get the message.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": "SomeExceptionFromServer",
    "data": {}
}
```

You might have to change `data` to your data property name.

Comment: Well, can you post a successful json response from the server?

Comment: 'cos when in  the callback method there is no way I can access msg. that's why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694012/how-to-get-responsecode-from-store-callback

Comment: this is wrong with that attempt http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196013-access-operation.response-when-success-false